# Clicking a button places user's current location on map using Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I understand how to get my current location with HTML5.

How do I add a click handler, so when a button is pressed it shows my current position on the map?

Google's example pretty much explains how it's done, but the button is set to predefined coordinates. How do I attach the "Home" button to current position coordinates instead?
[Custom Control Example](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomExample)

Answer (score 0):

From Google demo

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  initialLocation = new  google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
map.setCenter(initialLocation);
```

As initialLocation is global you can use this to set the click event listeners: simply set the map to initialLocation

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
map.setCenter(initialLocation)
});
```